# What does javascript:Function syntax mean?

Tags: javascript

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wener/aWuHp/)

```
javascript:Function("alert('this is ok')")();
```

same as

```
new Function("alert('this is ok')")();
```

What the syntax called ?

Any reference ?

**EDIT**

Sorry, my fault,it's only a label,and it's not equals `new`.

```
<script>
    javascript:C("val");
    wener:C("val");
    function C(v)
    {
        this.val = v;
        alert(window.val)
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript: alert('foo');">click me</a>
```

For `<a href="javascript: alert('foo');">click me</a>` see [URI_scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)(Thanks apsillers) and [draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03)

Comment: Neal gave the correct answer.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal My answer is gone :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "the old way of using JavaScript in attributes," relevant only in HTML.

You can also write:

```
poop:Function("alert('ohai')")();
```

Your example is just JavaScript code, not an HTML attribute, so it's just a label.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a fully qualified link, the text to the left of the colon is called the [*scheme*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

```
<a href="https://example.com/foo">foo</a>
           ^ scheme is "https"
```

Browsers allow you the specify a scheme of `javascript` in HTML markup, in which case the browser interprets the link content to the right of the colon as a script to be executed, instead of a destination resource.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('I am a script, formatted as a link!')">foo</a>
            ^ scheme is "javascript"
```

(Please, never do this; use `addEventListener("click", function() { ... })` instead.)

If you include the `javascript:` prefix in non-link contexts, however, it's interpreted as a [JavaScript label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). This is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be used when you want to execute JavaScript in browser's address bar. Copy/paste `javascript:Function("alert('this is ok')")();` into browser's address bar and hit Enter.